# My sql questions about retrieving multiple values from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, where-clause

MySQL tables:

```
author
(aEmail*
,fName
,lName
,bDate
,city
)

reviewer
(rEmail*
,phoneNumber
,lName
,fName
,city
)

paper
(paperId*
,title
,abstract
,submissionDate
)

author_paper
(authorId*
,paperId*
,isContact
)

paper_review
(paperId*
,reviewerId*
,score 
,reviewSubmissionDate
,reviewInvitationDate
)

* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```

How would I find authors that have made more than 3 papers and return their names in a query and that the authors age is above a certain age (aEmail = authorId)

Comment: Personally, I think it's a mistake to use real-world (and changeble) information as an internal FK reference. For further help, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery for filtering: we can just count how many rows each author has in `author_paper`.

```
select a.*
from author a
where (select count(*) from author_paper ap where ap.authorid = a.id) > 3
```

I am unsure about the correlation clause. Maybe you want to use the author's email instead:

```
where ap.authorid = a.aemail
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , the thing I was working on never specified where the author id comes from, but in this case only way to refer to author is through his/her email

Comment: @awdaDASDF: ok, so use the `where` clause that is suggested in the second part of the question.